# Troubleshooting Character Array Problem in Java

Tags: java, palindrome

I was going through a Palindrome( Specifically String Palindrome) Problem and was checking whether the string is palindrome or not. But a problem struck in the program

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n,flag=0;
    n=sc.nextInt();
    char a[]=new char[n];
    int l=0;
    int h=n-1;
    while(l<h)
    {

        if(a[l++]!=a[h--])
        {
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
        System.out.println("String is not Palindrome");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("String is Palindrome"); 
    }

}
```

So above is the code which I wrote but the problem is, I have created a character array instead of the string.
The main point of the argument is the above code correct in terms of code standards.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: By the way, your array `a`  always contains default values.

Comment: When you fix @Anatolii point also you can return right after the first time (a[l++]!=a[h--]) evaluates to true. Finally, this question is off-topic in my opinion.

Comment: Creating a character array is not a problem itself. What do you want precisely ?

Comment: `String` class also stores value internally as `char` array. To check string is Palindrome or not you need char wise comparison, so it absolutely fine to use char array. Even if you use some String API wrappers, internally it will do same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is the above code correct in terms of code standards

Not really:

- Don't name a local variable `l` (lowercase L). It is too easy to confuse with `1` (one).
  Since I don't know what `h` is supposed to be a shorthand for, I changed `l` and `h` to `i` and `j` below, as those are very common integer iterator variable names.
- Don't declare a local variable before it's needed. Use `int n = sc.nextInt();`
- Don't put array declaration on the variable name. Put it on the type, since it defines the type.
- Don't use `0` / `1` for `false` / `true` values. Change `flag` to a `boolean`, and name it better, e.g. describe its value. `notPalindrome` seems appropriate here. It helps document the code.
- The `while` loop should be a `for` loop. It helps keeping loop logic together, and isolated from other logic, and it helps limit the scope of the loop variable(s).

Those were my comments related to coding standards.

However, your code doesn't work, because you never get a string from the user. Your choice of using `char[]` is fine, but you need to change the logic for getting it. See code below for how to use [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) to do that.

Also, once a difference is found, you should exit the loop, either by also checking the boolean variable in the loop condition, or by using `break`. Personally, I prefer `break`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String sentence = sc.nextLine();
char[] a = sentence.toCharArray();

boolean notPalindrome = false;
for (int i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if (a[i] != a[j]) {
        notPalindrome = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (notPalindrome) {
    System.out.println("String is not Palindrome");
} else {
    System.out.println("String is Palindrome"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please use below code to check given String/number Palindrome or Not

```
public static void main(String args[])   {  
      String original, reverse = ""; 
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   
      System.out.println("Enter String "); 
      original = in.nextLine();   
      int n = original.length();   
      for ( int index = n - 1; index >= 0; index-- )  {
         reverse = reverse + original.charAt(index);
        }  
      if (original.equals(reverse))  {
        System.out.println("String is Palindrome");
     } else  {
           System.out.println("String is not Palindrome");  
    }

}
```